# flutter connection with python

Tags: python, flutter, http

I have been struggling to connect python script with flutter, my python script runs fine in browser, however in flutter the await http.get(url) returns the null or you can say it isn't executing at all (since i tried to add a print response but the nothing shows in console). I'm working on local server and using a usb port connected with me real device/phone. 

The IP that i'm using: `10.0.2.2:5000` and I have also tried `127.0.0.1:5000`

```
FlatButton(
onPressed: () async {
     var response = await http.get(url);
     print('hi$response'); // from this line, nothing executing 
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print(response.body);
          var decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
          setState(() {
              queryText = decodedData['Query'];
          });
          } else {
                print("server side error: ${response.body}");
          }
      },
child: Text("Click me")),
```

Then after some time it throws exception of `connection time out`.
**Update:** I guess my await has some issue as it returns null and stop executes the below line of code.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: are your laptop and your phone on same wifi or any other network ? apart from USB

Comment: @KrishBhanushali both are on same wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, i guess the `await` is not returning anything and thus no below lines (even the `print` line) executing. I have set the `host` to `0.0.0.0` in the app.run and uses the ipv4 address in flutter app and everything starts working.
**In python**:
 `app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`

**In Flutter**(the url is): 
http://192.168.1.2:5000/tt